# Circular dependency exists in makefile

Tags: makefile

I tried executing the following (found on a website)

```
.PHONY: coat shoes mobile sweater socks trousers shirt pants undershirt

# target    prerequisite           command
# ------------------------------------------------
coat:       shoes mobile sweater;  @echo put on $@
shoes:      socks trousers;        @echo put on $@
mobile:     trousers;              @echo put on $@
sweater:    shirt;                 @echo put on $@
socks:      ;                      @echo put on $@
trousers:   pants shirt;           @echo put on $@
shirt:      undershirt;            @echo put on $@
pants:      ;                      @echo put on $@
undershirt: ;                      @echo put on $@
```

But I am getting Circular dependency error when executed on cygwin.
Here is the output

```
     1  MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 2000 Borland
     2  Error: Circular dependency exists in makefile
     3    socks -> socks
     4  Error: Circular dependency exists in makefile
     5    shoes -> socks
     6  Error: Circular dependency exists in makefile
     7    mobile -> mobile
     8  Error: Circular dependency exists in makefile
     9    coat -> shoes
    10  Fatal: ';' does not exist - don't know how to make it
```

Need help...

Comment: -1 for adding unrelated tags on purpose.

Comment: @larsmans: People who has worked on c or on linux, might know the answer to this question. That's why I added.

Comment: People who have worked on *anything* might know the answer to this question. We have tags to help people find questions that match their expertise or the problems they're facing; adding irrelevant tags to pull in more eyes is an abuse of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GNU make. Here's the evidence:

1. You are using a make copyrighted to Borland, which indicates that the make you are using is not GNU make.
2. I've found the example [here](http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html). The author provides a link to GNU make, suggesting that his examples expect GNU make.
3. The make you are running interprets `;` as a dependency. Clearly it is not interpreting your Makefile correctly.
4. If I use GNU make with your example, here's what I get:

   ```
   $ make
   put on socks
   put on pants
   put on undershirt
   put on shirt
   put on trousers
   put on shoes
   put on mobile
   put on sweater
   put on coat
   ```